# Calculate Vacation on Anniversary date then Calendar year

Tags: function, ms-access, parameters, vba, date-arithmetic

I have a form in my Access database that calculated Vacation based on my company policy. The rule is after you first year of employment based on your anniversary date you get 40 hours. (ex. I was hired on 09/06/2012, I get 40 hours vacation on 09/06/2013.)

Then each subsequent year it rolls to calendar year. So using my above example I need to use my 40 hours between 09/06/2013 and 12/31/2013 or I lose them because on January 1, 2014 I recieve 40.

At three years, calendar date, I would get 80 hrs. for on 01/01/2016 I get 80 hours.

At 10 years, calendar date, it goes to 120. The code I have been using which continues to pull from the anniversary date follows:

```
  Function calcVacEarned(asOfDate As Date, HireDate As Date)


  Dim yos As Single
  Dim curryear As Integer
  Dim hireYear As Integer

  curryear = Year(asOfDate)
  hireYear = Year(HireDate)

  yos = (asOfDate - HireDate) / 365.25

  If yos >= 1 Then
    Select Case yos
      Case Is > 10
        calcVacEarned = 120
      Case Is > 3
        calcVacEarned = 80
      Case Is > 1
        calcVacEarned = 40
      Case Else
        calcVacEarned = 0
    End Select
  Else
    If hireYear >= curryear Then
      calcVacEarned = "0"
    Else
      If DateSerial(curryear, Month(HireDate), Day(HireDate)) = asOfDate Then
        calcVacEarned = "40"
      Else
        calcVacEarned = "0"
      End If
    End If
  End If

End Function
```

My company uses this on a daily basis to calculate hours across the board, could use some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have understood what you are asking. Here goes :

```
Function calcVacEarned(asOfDate As Date, HireDate As Date)  
    Dim anniversary As Boolean
    Dim yos as Integer
    anniversary = False
    yos = Year(asOfDate) - Year(HireDate)

    if Month(HireDate) = Month(asOfDate) And (yos = 1) then
      if Day(HireDate) <= Day(asOfDate) then
        anniversary = True
    end if
    elseif Month(HireDate) < Month(asOfDate) And (yos = 1) then
        anniversary = True 
    end if 

    if anniversary then
        calcVacEarned = 40
    else
        Select Case yos
          Case Is > 10
            calcVacEarned = 120
          Case Is > 3
            calcVacEarned = 80
          Case Is > 1
            calcVacEarned = 40
          Case Else
            calcVacEarned = 0
        End Select
    end if

End Function
```